# Xcode, SpriteKit: Rotating a whole scene, and editing properties of a sprite inside an array

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm using Xcode, SpriteKit to create a game. 2 questions:

1) I need the whole scene to rotate whenever a function is called:

```
- (void)mouseClick {
  // RotateWholeScene somehow
}
```

I know about rotating a sprite by changing its zrotation, but changing scene.zrotation doesn’t work.

Also, some things in the scene need to stay in the same position, like the score, etc.

I’d prefer it if there is a way which I can rotate the whole scene as if the camera view has changed, as there are calculations (like falling objects) which would be much easier to do if they aren’t needed to be changed in the code.

2) Right now the program creates a sprite each frame, and places the sprite into an array (which I declared at the start).

```
NSMutableArray *SomeArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];
```

And later on in the code:

```
- (void)CalledEachFrame {
  [self addChild: SomeSprite];
  [SomeArray addObject: SomeSprite];
}
```

Elsewhere in the code, I need:

```
- (void)AlsoCalledEachFrame {
  for (int i; i < X; i++) {
    SomeArray[i].position = A;
  }
}
```

This (and several other attempts) doesn't work, and I get an error:

[image]

***EDIT: My bad. In the image, I showed, I set the position to an integer rather than a CGPoint. Nevertheless, the same error occur even if I put a CGPoint instead of those 99s.

Comment: Why would you want to manually rotate the screen? That's something the device handles by itself.

Comment: Your array is holding objects of type 'id' which is a generic object. When adding to your array you should be adding SKNode, SKSpriteNode, etc... kind of object in order for the position command to work.

Comment: I need to rotate the screen every frame, because that's part of the game (rotate the screen by like 10 degrees at a time for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asking two questions at once here. I should discourage that. Nevertheless, here goes:

1) I faced a similar problem and my solution to this problem was putting the *scene* nodes and the *hud* nodes each in a separate child nodes of the SKScene subclass, like so:

```
@interface SKSceneSubclass : SKScene 

// ...

@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) SKNode *sceneContents;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) SKNode *hud;

@end
```

In the scene initializer, I'd put:

```
- (instancetype)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
      self.sceneContents = [SKNode new];
      [self addChild:self.sceneContents];

      self.hud = [SKNode new];
      [self addChild:self.hud];
      self.hud.zPosition = 20.f; // ensures the hud on top of sceneContents

      // your custom stuff
      // ...
    }

    return self;
  }
```

This requires you to decide upon adding child nodes which node (sceneContents or hud) will be their parent.

```
  [self.sceneContents addChild:newSprite];
  [self.hud addChild:someCoolHudButton];
```

Then, you can just run `[SKAction rotateByAngle:angle duration:duration]` on the *sceneContents* node. The *hud* and its children will not be affected. I am currently employing this method to move and zoom *sceneContents* while having a stationary HUD which behaves as it should.

2) The problem is that you are not telling the compiler the item you're accessing is an SKNode object, so the compiler does not allow you to access the `position` property. If you are certain only the array will only contain SKNodes or subclasses thereof, use the `forin` iterator method.

```
for (<#type *object#> in <#collection#>) {
  <#statements#>
}
```

In your case, it would look like this.

```
CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(x, y);
for (SKNode *node in SomeArray) {
  node.position = newPosition;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about asking 2 questions at once.. However StackOverflow didn't allow me to post several questions in a row for 90 mins (I had 3 questions I wanted to ask at the time). Is there a way around this (other than waiting)?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually rotate the view with this code:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0.1); // change value to desires angle
self.view.transform = transform;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work - I add this into a MouseDown handler, but on the 2nd line of your code, it returns an error "Property 'transform' not found on object of type 'SKView *' "

Comment: ****Ah I see the problem. It works only on iOS builds - but I also want to run the game on OS X builds too. Is there a similar property for that too? Nevertheless, I think I'll still have the problem that I don't want some labels to be rotated, so I think prefer ClockedEddy's solution for this game.